# How to hide some of the view while all are aligned with equal width constraint?

Tags: ios, constraints

I have 6 views in row V1, V2,... V6 all are aligned in one row one after another with equal width constraint. Now on a particular condition, I want to hide two of them (V1 and V6). I can't hide them by taking outlet of width constraint and assign it **Widthconstraint.constant = 0** because of equal width constraint. How to tackle this condition?

Tried to do by using **isHidden or alpha = 0** but want to align other views (V2, V3, V4, V5) properly without blank space of V1 and V6

Comment: A screenshot would be  more appropriate to understand the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually setting the `width` constraint or setting them equal contraints each, use horizontal `UIStackview` with equal spacing.

Then whenever needed to hide a view, just use `isHidden`, `UIStackview` will automatically adjust the width each of the view to accomodate the space left.

Check your scenario here

```
import UIKit

class StackviewController : UIViewController {
    let stackview: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .horizontal
        view.distribution = .fillEqually
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let view1: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let view2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let view3: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.addSubview(stackview)

        stackview.addArrangedSubview(view1)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(view2)
        stackview.addArrangedSubview(view3)


        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            stackview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),            
            ])

//        view2.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Uncomment the line

```
//        view2.isHidden = true
```

Then you'll see the green view is gone, and other two taking the space equally.

Comment: Thanks @Ratul it's working fine with the above solution.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the ideal use case for a horizontal UIStackView, assuming the views have the same height. That way if you set isHidden = true, they will not take up the space they do when being shown.